# How Can I Find Unique Values in this Dataframe with pandas?

Tags: database, dataframe

I have a dataframe (image attached for reference), which is a list of venues in neighborhoods of Toronto.

For each venue the neighborhood name is listed, as well as the venue type (I got rid of everything else).

I need to find a way to grab the total number of unique venue types in each neighborhood. So for example, if there are 8 coffee shops and 2 restaurants, the value returned should be 2. If there's 1 coffee shop, 1 restaurant and 1 laundromat, the value should be 3, etc.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'groupby' and 'nunique'

```
df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['Venue Category'].nunique()
```

This will return the count of all the different 'Venue Category' for each 'Neighbourhood'.
Hope this solves your question :)

Comment: Awesome, this is almost all the way there. This returns a unique list for each neighborhood... but do you know how to have it return a number instead of a list?

Comment: This query returned:

Neighborhood
Agincourt                                                                                                                                 [Breakfast Spot, Lounge, Latin American Restau...
Alderwood, Long Branch                                                                                                                    [Pizza Place, Gym, Pub, Coffee Shop, Sandwich ...
Bathurst Manor, Wilson Heights, Downsview North                                                                                          

Do you know what type of object this is?

Comment: i guess you have used `unique` instead of `nunique`.
`unique` returns a unique list while `nunique` returns the number of unique elements.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's exactly what happened! Thanks.

Comment: This is the result:

Neighborhood
Agincourt                                                                                                                                  4
Alderwood, Long Branch                                                                                                                     6
Bathurst Manor, Wilson Heights, Downsview North                                                                                           19

It looks like a string. Do you know how to turn this to a dataframe?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: use, `df.groupby(col,as_index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas' `unique()` function

List unique values in the `df['neighborhood']` column

```
df.neighborhood.unique()
```

Should return an array/list of values

Comment: This gives me a list of each unique neighborhood, but I need a list, or dictionary, of each unique venue in each neighborhood. So something like "Victoria Village: 5"